# Failed assertion: line 42 pos 16: 'path.isNotEmpty': is not true. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-2

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what to do so I am back again with the issue related to the question already posted by me on stack overflow Error: Failed assertion: line 42 pos 16: 'path.isNotEmpty': is not true. flutter

The 42 pos 16: is in the setstate

```
setState(() {
          docsSnap = docs;
        });
```

Please help I've been on this for hours still stuck not sure how to go on about it

```
`class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  late Screen size;
  int _selectedIndex = -1;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<Property> recentList =  [];
  List<Property> topList =  [];
  var citiesList = ["Ahmedabad", "Mumbai", "Anand", "Delhi ", "Vadodara", "Chennai","Goa","Kolkata","Indore","Jaipur"];
  Image? image1;
  String? docRef;
  String? isLoggedIn;
  DocumentSnapshot? docsSnap;
  String? userRef;

  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async{
    isLoggedIn= await LocalStorage.sharedInstance.loadAuthStatus(Constants.isLoggedIn);
    docRef= await LocalStorage.sharedInstance.loadUserRef(Constants.userRef);
    print('docRef :'+ docRef!);
    if(docRef != "NULL"){
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('/User/'+docRef!).get().then((DocumentSnapshot docs) {
        print("Doc found");
        setState(() {
          docsSnap = docs;
        });
      });
    }else{
      setState((){docsSnap=null;});
      print("Doc Not Exist");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getUserDetails();

    image1 = Image.asset("assets/drawer_design.png", gaplessPlayback: true);

    topList
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Omkar Lotus", propertyLocation:"Ahmedabad ", image:"feature_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"26000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Sandesh Heights", propertyLocation:"Baroda ", image:"feature_2.jpg", propertyPrice:"11500", propertyDesc: '', id: ''));

    recentList
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Vishwas CityRise", propertyLocation:"Pune ", image:"hall_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"17500", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Gift City", propertyLocation:"Ahmedabad ", image:"hall_2.jpeg", propertyPrice:"13500000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''));
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    precacheImage(image1!.image, context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(true);
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setNavigationBarWhiteForeground(true);
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.blue[700]);
    size = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: AnnotatedRegion(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: backgroundColor,
            statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            systemNavigationBarColor: backgroundColor),
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                upperPart()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: docsSnap != null ? drawer(image1,context,docsSnap![""].data()['profileImage'],docsSnap![""].data()['firstName']+" "+docsSnap![""].data()['lastName'],docsSnap![""].data()['email'],"true",'/User/'+docRef!)
          : drawer(image1,context,'assets/icons/avatar.png','Login / Register ','','false',null),
    );
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Correct URL Format: If you're using a URL, make sure it includes the protocol (e.g., http:// or https://). For example: http://example.com or https://api.example.com.